# How to center a dynamic width button inside a fixed width div?

Tags: html, css, button, center

I have submit buttons or normal buttons of varying width depending upon their values wrapped inside fixed divs.  Now the buttons won't center inside the div even after having `margin: 0 auto;` and `display:block;` because of the missing `width` property. How to have them centered without explicitly setting the width for each button ?

```
input[type="submit"], .button {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: white;
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 0 auto !important;
      clear: both;
      padding: 5px 7px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: "Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
      background: #4797ED;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are inline elements. Is the `display:block` necessary for other reasons or does anything speak against generally centering all text/inline-elements within the div?

If not, you could assign `text-align:center` to the div instead and remove `display:block` from the button.

As a side note, your current style centers the button in FF12. What browser are you using? Edit: Also works in IE9 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLPE4/)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cannot assign `text-align:center` to my div, because I have other text also wrapped inside the same div. Is there any way to center the button by tweaking the css for button?

Comment: @Vivek You'd either need to set a width on the button, or else add a, extra wrapper element around the button with `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `input[type="submit"], .button {}`
to `display: inline-block;`. Then set the parent `div` to `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gSaBj/1/

check out this url....

Comment: You have added `width` and `height` to the css of the button. But here, I cannot set a fixed `width` and `height` to the buttons. I have removed the width and height properties and wrapped the button inside a div and the result is this `http://jsfiddle.net/gSaBj/1/` The button is not centered.

Comment: @vivek : you want center of Container of submit button Horizontally and vertically both right?

Comment: Just centering the button horizontally would do for me.